# Query not working when I target a different column with exact same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Known working query fails when I target a different column(same data types). This query works:

```
Select * from assets WHERE type = '' AND os LIKE '%7%' AND status <> 'Discarded'
```

BUT this query doesn't work (it returns empty set):

```
Select * from assets WHERE model = '' AND os LIKE '%7%' AND status <> 'Discarded'
```

The ONLY difference is the column `type` is changed to `model`. Both columns are `varchar` and there are records that meet both of the query conditions. I have tried putting `` around the field names, it didn't help.

Comment: `model = ''` should probably be `model IS NULL`

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. What is happening is that the records that are NULL in the status field don't show. If I set the status to 'In Use', then only those show up. I think I need to change the value from NULL to 'Unassessed'... then It would work.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: expression `AND status <> 'Discarded'` does not allow `NULL` values.

In SQL, `NULL <> 'Discarded'` is false, just like `NULL = 'Discarded'` is false as well. To check for nullness, you need to use `IS NULL`.

I think that your query should be expressed as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM assets 
WHERE 
    model = '' 
    AND os LIKE '%7%' 
    AND (status IS NULL OR status <> 'Discarded')
```

NB: it might be worth noting that storing empty strings is, generaly speaking, not a good idea. It is usually simpler to use `NULL` as a default value.